# Java application wrapped runs faster on Windows 7 in Windows XP Compatibility mode

Tags: java, windows-7-x64

Java application runs faster on Windows 7 in Windows XP compatibility mode according to some of my customers, but why ?

I dont seem to have the problem myself, yet they find the application seems to be consuming 100% cpu whilst doing nothing, simply setting the properties of either the exe or a batch file that calls the java to Windows XP compatibility  mode fixes it , how could that be ?

Comment: I'm not saying that I know why, but did you check to see if it was a 32 bit JVM or a 64 bit JVM?

Comment: Be thankful your customers have found a solution that works for them.  Is your Java application 32 bit or 64 bit?  Are your customers' Windows 7 machines 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Yeah, I think the Windows7 is 64bit, the application can be 32bit or 64bit, to be frank as I cannot replicate the problem myself Im struggling to track this down, but was wondering if anyone could understand why an application could run better in Compatability mode

Comment: Perhaps the wrapper is the main culprit on this (using Windows XP features), by the way what wrapper you use?

Comment: @Rafael , jsmooth but one customers reports issue just using a batch file and pure java

Comment: Well, JSmooth is 32 bits only and pretty outdated (last release was in 2007), so probably uses old Windows XP calls, regarding your user using only a batch file, he may be using an outdated version of the JVM (like 1.5 or something like that).

Answer (score 4):

No definite answer but just a way to diagnose on site what is happening exactly.

You have to be confirm which process is consuming CPU and what it is doing exactly, for instance by monitoring system calls done: the *sysinternals* tools like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) should lead to clues about what may be wrong. At least, you may compare execution profile with versus without XP compatibility mode.

As the problem may come from the Java application itself, you should give a try of a JVM profiling with tools like [Netbeans Profiler](http://profiler.netbeans.org/). Maybe the code relies on some old Windows XP specific stuff like directory structure or environment variable that no longer exist or have changed in Windows 7 (but you kept/reapplied on your own installation)... leading to an improper error handling and infinite loop of retries for instance.

A native windows profiler may be an option too but it is far too difficult to analyze without JVM source code, and when Java code is concerned because of JIT.

Answer (score 0):

No direct solution, but your question is pretty open ended.

If your customer can reproduce this consistently, you might see if they are willing to send you a [remote assistance request](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457004.aspx), letting you onto their desktop.  Then at least you can see the problem in action, and try debugging it on their machine using the tools mentioned by others.

Answer (score -1):

Its because of the switching of tasks internally. Switching of tasks in Windows Xp in compatibility mode is more compared to Windows 7. It may cause because of firewall also. Check your firewall status in Windows 7.

Comment: What did you mean? Switching what tasks, internally to what? "switching... is more compared to windows 7". More what? Can you give some source?

Comment: I think he's suggesting that internal task switching in XP mode is have more performance than original 7 one.